# pointer to array of integers and normal array of integers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, types, kr-c

In KR C book page 112 it says that following:

```
int (*arr1)[10];
```

is a pointer to an array of 10 integers. I don't get what's difference between above and:

```
int arr2[10];
```

1- Isn't `arr2` itself a pointer to array of 10 integers? (Because name of an array is a pointer itself.)

2- If the name of an array is the array address and pointer to that array, then both `arr1` and `arr2` are pointer to array of integers, isn't this true?

Comment: How big is a pointer `printf("%zu\n", sizeof arr1);`? --> maybe 4 or 8, etc.  How big is the array `printf("%zu\n", sizeof arr2);`? --> maybe 40 or 80, etc.

Answer (score 5):

> Isn't arr2 itself a pointer to array of 10 integers?

No, it's an array.

> Isn't the name of an array the array address and pointer to that array?

Array names can be/are converted to pointers *to their 0th element* (not the entire array).

> So both arr1 and arr2 are pointer to array of integers?

No.

1. `arr1` is a pointer to an array of 10 integers.
2. `arr2` is an array of 10 integers.  In most contexts it converts to a pointer to an integer (not a pointer to an array).

---

Check this *wrong* example for instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr2[10] = {0};
    arr2[5] = 747;

    int (*arr1)[10] = {0};
    arr1[5] = 747;

    return 0;
}
```

Here I am treating both `arr1` and `arr2` as the "same thing", and I got this error:

```
C02QT2UBFVH6-lm:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
main.c:9:13: error: array type 'int [10]' is not assignable
    arr1[5] = 747;
    ~~~~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

But if I do:

```
arr1[0][5] = 747;
```

it will pass compilation! Same with `(*arr1)[5] = 747;` of course.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship between arrays and pointers is one of the more confusing aspects of C. Allow me to explain by way of example. The following code fills and displays a simple one-dimensional array:

```
void showArray( int *ptr, int length )
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
        printf( "%d ", ptr[i] );
    printf( "\n" );
}

int main( void )
{
    int array[10];
    for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        array[i] = i;
    showArray( array, 10 );
}
```

You can see that when an array is passed to a function, the array name is taken as a pointer to the first element of the array. In this example, the first element is an `int`, so the pointer is an `int *`.

Now consider this code that fills and prints a two-dimensional array:

```
void showArray( int (*ptr)[10], int rows, int cols )
{
    for ( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ )
    {
        for ( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
            printf( "%2d ", ptr[r][c] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int array[5][10];
    for ( int row = 0; row < 5; row++ )
        for ( int col = 0; col < 10; col++ )
            array[row][col] = row * 10 + col;
    showArray( array, 5, 10 );
}
```

The array name is still a pointer to the first element of the array. But in this example the first element of the array is itself an array, specifically an array of 10 `int`. So the pointer in the function is a *pointer to an array of 10 `int`*.

What I hope to impress upon you is that a pointer of the form `(int *ptr)[10]` has some correspondence to a two-dimensional array, whereas a pointer of the form `int *ptr` has some correspondence to a one-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

[cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) will show you what C interprets your variable declaration as. Quite handy as you start getting into more complicated variable declarations.

[int arr2[10];](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20arr2%5B10%5D%3B)
 declare arr2 as array 10 of int

[int (*arr1)[10];](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int%20%28*arr1%29%5B10%5D%3B)
 declare arr1 as pointer to array 10 of int